# Push объекта в массив

Tags: vue.js

При нажатии на кнопку Enter приходят данные. Нужно эти данные добавить в массив, но при методе push возникает ошибка.

```
data: function() {
        return  {
            messages: [
                {
                    userName: 'Sergey',
                    message: 'Hello'
                }
            ],
        }
    },
```

Есть div, в котором отображаются

```
<div class="col users border scrollbar" id="messages-canvas">
            <div v-for="message in messages">
                {{ message.userName }}: {{ message.message }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку выполняю метод

```
methods: {
        enterClicked() {
            this.messages.push({
                userName: 'Dima',
                message: 'Yes'
            });
        }
    }
```

Ошибка при добавлении

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы точно привели тот код, который не работает?

Comment: Да, я разобрался

Нужно использовать стрелочные функции, так как у обычный функций есть свой this